# Ruby extension with multiple targets

Tags: ruby

I need to create some ruby extension which will contain multiple `.so` objects after compilation (I need it to contain 2 shared libraries). How can I do it using `mkmf` gem? It's default function to crate makefile, `create_makefile`, only accepts 1 target which it compiles using `-shared` option.